# CF7 Downloading file with multi form page

Tags: contact-form-7

I am not a developer so please don't close this question, please.
In contact form 7 I try to download a file after making a lead.

That's ok with :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( 'MyformID-1' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/file-1.pdf', '_self');    
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

(I put this code on the concerned page only)

But on some page I have 2 or 3 form which have one different file to download each time. It runs with duplicate the all script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( 'MyformID-1' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/file-1.pdf', '_self');    
    }
}, false );
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( 'MyformID-2' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/file-2.pdf', '_self');    
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

I think it is possible to make all this into one `<script>` but I don't know how.

I've made several tests without success, so here I am.

I also tried the code shown here with no success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( 'MyformID-1' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/strong.pdf', '_self');   
    }
    if ( 'MyformID-2' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/green.pdf', '_self');   
    }
    if ( 'MyformID-3' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        window.open('https://www.example.com/orange.pdf', '_self');   
    }
}, false );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let filenames = {
    ['MyformID-1']: 'some.pdf',
    ['MyformID-2']: 'files.pdf',
    ['MyformID-3']: 'to.pdf',
    ['MyformID-4']: 'b.pdf',
    ['MyformID-5']: 'processed.pdf'
};
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if (filenames[event.detail.contactFormId]) {
        window.open(`https://www.example.com/file-${filenames[event.detail.contactFormId]}`, '_self');
    }
}, false );
```

Explanation:

- we have `filenames` as key-value pair of files, containing the supported pairs of (contact form id; filename)
- we can use a single listener
- if the `contactFormId` is supported
- then we redirect to a link
- specified with a string template
- where we pass the filename associated to the contact form id as a template literal

We could also resolve this with a regular expression that would look like **^MyformID-[0-9]*$** (I'm not a regexp specialist, so if there is a typo, I would welcome any observations), but I think it's important to make sure that you understand the solution.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I realise my exemple influence you in a wrong way.
file-1.pdf and file-2.pdf are not named as this but with very different filename between each other.

Comment: @ProTips I think we can agree that based on the question this was a logical answer. So, if the filenames differ, then you need to provide more information about the filenames.

Comment: Yes, you right, I shouldnt  write my question as it. I'm sorry about that. You can considere filename are very different each type like a mini sentence.

Comment: @ProTips thanks for clarifying. To cope with this problem we can create an object that will represent key-value pairs for the contact form id and the filename. I have edited my answer and elaborated this idea.